# Remote Desktop can't find the computer

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, remote-desktop

This is my first attempt in setting up some VMs. I am trying to rdp to them but I'm encountering this error

**Remote Desktop can't find the computer "[Server]". This might mean that "[Server]" does not belong to the specified network. Verify the computer name and domain that you are trying to connect to.**

I am trying to set up some dev servers. I have made 6 machines in Hyper-V, 1 domain controller and 5 member servers.

All running Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1. All on a domain (call it "d.com").

I have created an Internal virtual switch, configuring it as follows:

- IPv4 Address = 198.168.10.1
- Subnet Mask = 255.255.255.0
- DNS Server = 198.168.10.1

For the Domain Controller (call it "DC") and the first member server (call it "S1"), I enabled Remote Desktop allowing for connections from computers running any version following [this](https://briantjackett.com/2010/06/06/how-to-configure-remote-desktop-to-hyper-v-guest-virtual-machines/) link's instructions. I did set the services listed in this instruction to start automatically:

- DNS Client (already automatic)
- Function Discovery Resource Publication
- SSDP Discovery
- UPnP Device Host

I'm able to ping the IP given above. I checked to see if it's a firewall issue by disabling the firewall in S1 and attempted to rdp but was met with the same error.

Wierdly I was able to rdp yesterday when I first set it all up, but today no such luck. I did spot that the SSDP Discovery service had not started when I spun up the machine, but even starting that did not resolve the issue.

Is there some configuration I'm missing?
Have I misconfigured something?

---

**EDIT: RESOLVED**

I amended the IP config of the internal switch, giving it an IP on the same subnet as the VMs, with appropriate subnet mask, and a default gateway (again on the same subnet). I have also removed the DNS server address.

I am now able to ping and remote desktop my VMs from the host machine.

Comment: did you try bridge network in VMware?

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Bridge network in your VMware workstation.Outside devices on same network cannot communicate with VMware machine working inside OS. 
Please see here in my post how Bridge connection works.

[How Bridge Work](https://serverfault.com/questions/85423/a-ping-b-ok-b-ping-a-destination-host-unreachable-firewall-off/878688#878688)

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading on how to do this, am I correct in thinking that in Hyper-V bridging involves creating and assigning an external virtual switch?

Comment: Bridge network  generate new ip address inside router network.

Comment: I have a network bridge and I have added virtual switch to the bridge, which is also used by a Wi-Fi adapter. I went through Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections. However I am still unable to rdp. I do see that this virtual switches IPv4 connectivity is "Not Connected", is this expected?

Comment: Can both server and remote ping each other?

Comment: I am not able to, "transmit failed. general failure."... I am currently going through this website's trouble shooting / resolution steps.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot the [link](http://www.corenetworkz.com/2011/08/ping-transmit-failed-general-failure.html)

Comment: Created another VM and was rdp. The difference was I configured a new virtual switch for this VM to be on the same subnet as the host as well as give the VM an IP on the same subnet. So, I believe I simply need to change the IP of all my VMs. Thanks for all your help none the less @TAHASULTANTEMURI